# Is there a way to use gevent in ipython notebook?

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook, gevent

I'm using a library that imports gevent. I would like to run it in ipython notebook. My first cell is:

```
print 'foo'
import library
print 'bar'
```

but neither print happens. I guess the library patches thread, otherwise it should work: https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/2785/#issuecomment-48009193

My ipython file (`/usr/local/bin/ipython`) looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
import sys

from IPython import start_ipython

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.argv[0] = re.sub(r'(-script\.pyw|\.exe)?$', '', sys.argv[0])
    sys.exit(start_ipython())
```

I tried running a copy of it with the monkey patching at the top, based on asuggestion here: https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/4771. ipython loads up fine, but ipython notebook doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this, interactively in your python shell. When you get it working, then create the script that you need to run from the command line.

```
python3
Python 3.4.1 (v3.4.1:c0e311e010fc, May 18 2014, 00:54:21) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import IPython
>>> IPython.start_ipython (argv = ['notebook', '--no-browser'])
[I 17:31:43.672 NotebookApp] Using MathJax from CDN: https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js
[I 17:31:43.709 NotebookApp] The port 8888 is already in use, trying another random port.
[W 17:31:43.712 NotebookApp] Terminals not available (error was No module named 'terminado')
[I 17:31:43.713 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /Users/fred/Dropbox/notebooks
[I 17:31:43.713 NotebookApp] 0 active kernels 
[I 17:31:43.713 NotebookApp] The IPython Notebook is running at: http://localhost:8889/
[I 17:31:43.713 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
```

The --no-browser option avoids launching a browser directly. Omit that if you want the local browser started automatically. In this example, you can point your browser to `http://localhost:8889/`. Normally by default, it would be on port 8888.